# Can sqoop export blob type from HDFS to Mysql?

Tags: sqoop

Can Sqoop export blob type from HDFS to Mysql?

I have a table with blob type column, and I can import it to HDFS, but when export it back it raises exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not buffer record
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlRecordWriter.write(AsyncSqlRecordWriter.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlRecordWriter.write(AsyncSqlRecordWriter.java:46)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:639)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskInputOutputContext.write(TaskInputOutputContext.java:80)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:84)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException: com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.BlobRef
    at java.lang.Object.clone(Native Method)
    at org.apache.sqoop.lib.LobRef.clone(LobRef.java:109)
    at TblPlugin.clone(TblPlugin.java:270)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlRecordWriter.write(AsyncSqlRecordWriter.java:213)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Major Bug of Sqoop and it is still in open Status.

For more details see [Not able to export blob datatype from HDFS to MySQL](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-991)

Hope this gives information about your issue.